# get notification intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

My notification Show Method:

```
public static void ShowNotification(int id, String NotifFirstText,
        String NotifTitle, String NotifeText, int notificon, long when) {

    try {
        Context context = ApplicationClass.context;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int icon = notificon;
        CharSequence notiText = NotifFirstText;
        long meow = when;

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText, meow);
        CharSequence contentTitle = NotifTitle;
        CharSequence contentText = NotifeText;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        String mPackage = "mypackage";
        String mClass = ".ActivityShow";
        notificationIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,
                mPackage + mClass));
        notificationIntent.putExtra("id", id);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
                | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL
                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context,
                0, notificationIntent,0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED = id;
        notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and this my activity code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id") + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

i create more than one notification and set different id for All of them but when i click on each notification i give same id ...

how solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, 0, notificationIntent,0)`, extras do not get replaced per the [PendingIntent overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)). If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)), then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

While in most cases you'd replace the last `0` with [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) to update the extras, this doesn't help the problem of having multiple notifications simultaneously, instead they say:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents.

The easiest way to do this is to pass in your `id` as the request code (the second parameter). This ensures that each PendingIntent is managed separately:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(G.context, id, notificationIntent, 0)
```